# Error in finetune paddleOCR

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, training, optical-character-recognition, kaggle

Anyone help me this error in finetuning paddleOCR. Here the link to Notebook  https://www.kaggle.com/code/ryanlliu/finetune-paddleocr?scriptVersionId=169451466
and dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ryanlliu/vietnamese-id-card-fields/data
[image]